# Producing a bell shaped curve from an exponential function.

Tags: statistics

I have an exponentially distributed variable across time and I wish to convert it to a normal distribution. The exponential data I have should fit into the tail of the normal distribution. I know the mean/ median and of the theoretical normal distribution that I wish to produce.

Comment: There is a technical problem, because an exponential distribution is single-sided, while a normal one is not. Why precisely do you want to achieve this ? Do you want a half-normal ?

Comment: I imagine it should logistic towards the mean and then mirror on the opposite side. I was looking at modelling an infectious disease where the mean would be a 50% population point (which is know), but only the initial exponential points are known.

Comment: Yes, if you want to model growth in a finite population, a logistic curve is more appropriate. But your explanation with "exponentially distributed variable" is misleading.

Comment: The [latest 3blue1brown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kas0tIxDvrg) talks about this. A key point is that true exponential growth never occurs in the real world where resources always have limits. It only looks exponential until those limitations start to be felt.